# ng-click function not able to call service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angularjs-scope

I'm retrieving data from the web-api on click of a button but when i execute this code i get error `405`.

```
var app = angular.module("angularApp");
app.controller("loginController", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.login = function () {
        $http.get('http://localhost:35456/api/customer/Dipti123/dipti').
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //$scope.posts = data;
            alert("recived data");
            //alert(data.data.ID);
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // log error
            alert("error");
        });
    };        
});
```

Also if i call the `$http` method outside the `$scope.login` function i'm able able to receive the data but not on click of login function. 
can anyone let me know?

Comment: can you post the full error content

Comment: Check if get is allowed on API you are calling.

Comment: 405 means that the method you are requesting is not allowed. Have you allowed a GET method in your server side code?

Comment: Any other errors in the `console`? Also, `if i call the $http method outside the $scope.login` Do you mean in the controller body itself? Or something else? Is your app run under `35456` port, or different one?

Comment: yes $http method when called in the controller body itself i m able to receive the data and the app is running under differernt port@mosh Feu

Answer (score 1):

There may be two problems.

1. Did you mention `onclick` or `ng-click`. If you mention `onclick`, change it to `ng-click`.
2. See below code

   ```
   var app = angular.module("angularApp");

   app.controller("loginController" ,[ '$scope' , '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
   $scope.login = function () {
       $http.get('http://localhost:35456/api/customer/Dipti123/dipti')
       .then(function(res){
          console.log(res);
          console.log(res.data);
       }, function(error){
          alert(error);
       }
   };
   }]);
   ```

Make sure the api url correct or not. To test, make a request to local `json` data first, then try with api

Comment: @saurav by executing this code i m getting the error [object Object] as popup and i m using ng-click and also the url of api is correct

Answer (score 0):

For Resolving this please follow below step :

First Make sure in which side problem lies : Client or Server(Web API in your case).

Put some Console Log in angular and also put debugger in Webapi .

Once you get that it will be easier to narrow down exact issue.